# Left Join works in Access but not Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql

I have the following code in Javascript:

```js
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var monthStart = "01-" + month + "-" + year;
var monthEnd = daysInMonth(month, year) + "-" + month + "-" + year;
var personData = myDB.query("SELECT Personnel.ID, Personnel.Name, Personnel.Rank, " +
    "Personnel.Employee, Personnel.SkillLevel, Personnel.Specialty, Personnel.LeadDuties, " +
    "Personnel.ExtraDuties, Personnel.Organization, Personnel.Qual, Personnel.DOR, " +
    "Personnel.DAS, Personnel.Supervisor, Personnel.SupervisorRank, Personnel.EPRCloseOutDate, " +
    "Schedules.LinkID, Schedules.BeginDate, Schedules.EndDate, Schedules.Shift, " +
    "Schedules.DaysOff FROM Personnel LEFT JOIN Schedules ON " +
    "Schedules.LinkID = Personnel.ID AND ((BeginDate BETWEEN #"+monthStart+"# and " +
    "#"+monthEnd+"#) OR (EndDate BETWEEN #"+monthStart+"# and #"+monthEnd+"#) OR " +
    "(BeginDate <=#"+monthStart+"# AND EndDate >=#"+monthEnd+"#)) ORDER BY Schedules.Shift");
```

The output looks like this:

> SELECT Personnel.ID, Personnel.Name, Personnel.Rank, Personnel.Employee, Personnel.SkillLevel, Personnel.Specialty, Personnel.LeadDuties, Personnel.ExtraDuties, Personnel.Organization, Personnel.Qual, Personnel.DOR, Personnel.DAS, Personnel.Supervisor, Personnel.SupervisorRank, Personnel.EPRCloseOutDate, Schedules.LinkID, Schedules.BeginDate, Schedules.EndDate, Schedules.Shift, Schedules.DaysOff FROM Personnel LEFT JOIN Schedules ON Schedules.LinkID = Personnel.ID AND ((BeginDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (EndDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (BeginDate <=#01-June-2014# AND EndDate >=#30-June-2014#)) ORDER BY Schedules.Shift

But I get an error when I run it:

> "JOIN expression not supported"

Interestingly when I run this SQL statement in Access, it works:

> SELECT Personnel.ID, Personnel.Name, Personnel.Rank, Personnel.Employee, Personnel.SkillLevel, Personnel.Specialty, Personnel.LeadDuties, Personnel.ExtraDuties, Personnel.Organization, Personnel.Qual, Personnel.DOR, Personnel.DAS, Personnel.Supervisor, Personnel.SupervisorRank, Personnel.EPRCloseOutDate, Schedules.LinkID, Schedules.BeginDate, Schedules.EndDate, Schedules.Shift, Schedules.DaysOff
>       FROM Personnel LEFT JOIN Schedules ON Schedules.LinkID = Personnel.ID AND ((BeginDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (EndDate BETWEEN #01-June-2014# and #30-June-2014#) OR (BeginDate <=#01-June-2014# AND EndDate >=#30-June-2014#))
>       ORDER BY Schedules.Shift;

If I put a parenthesis starting after `'FROM'` and ending after the last two parenthesis, I get the same error.  What am I not seeing?

Comment: Building up a SQL statement in JS is a very bad idea; don't do it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I guess I wasn't worried about this since I am using JS in an HTA application where everything is client-side.